# Xming window not showing (Solaris/Windows)

Tags: installation, solaris, sybase, wizard, xming

I am trying to launch an install wizard window from a Solaris 9 system on my Windows 7 host to install Sybase ASE but the window won't show.

I am using Putty, with X11 forwarding enabled, and Xming on my Windows host. I am getting no error from the Solaris system. It just says `Running InstallShield Wizard...` and on my Windows, when I try to exit Xming it says `There are currently 1 clients connected.`

[image]

So clearly, my Solaris is connected to Xming, but I can't see the window.

Comment: You may want to use the CLI installer instead, or install from the Solaris system.  Otherwise there are just too many moving parts to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Can you get any other window to display, like an `xterm`?  What's the output from `xdpyinfo`?  This may be helpful:  https://wiki.utdallas.edu/wiki/display/FAQ/X11+Forwarding+using+Xming+and+PuTTY, along with this:  http://www.geo.mtu.edu/geoschem/docs/putty_install.html

Comment: I get a long output from `xdpyinfo` basically saying my display localhost:10.0 has 1 screen and bunch of stuff about color configuration and others... I can open an xterm after installing it.

Comment: *I get a long output from xdpyinfo basically saying my display localhost:10.0 has 1 screen and bunch of stuff about color configuration and others... I can open an xterm after installing it.*  That means your X connection is working and the problem is in the installer.

Comment: Yes I agree. I got it working before. So I don't understand why it won't show anymore now for some reason. Mean time I proceeded to the installation using the console mode of the installer.

Comment: You can run it under `truss -f -vall -l -o /output/file/name ../install/...`, and as long as you're running as root or there aren't any setuid/setgid processes started, you'll see every system call the install process tries.  Then you'll need to make sense of all the data to figure out *why* it's failing.

Answer (score -1):

You have to allow the solaris server to connect to the XMING config file by adding the server IP Address in the file X0.hosts (XMING install folder) then restart the XMING server on your PC. If it still does not work, try running "xhosts +" from Solaris command and export DISPLAY=your_server_IP_Address:0.0.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I added the ip of my solaris server in the X0.hosts file. But I can't find the command "xhosts". Also when I do `export DISPLAY=my_ip:0.0` I then get `The installer is unable to run in graphical mode.` How come my Xming server says (when I mouse over it): `Xming Server:0.0`.

Comment: Randomly changing DISPLAY variables and running `xhost` on the X Windows *client* isn't going to fix anything.

Comment: Running xhost + says `access control disabled, clients can connect from any host`. And I can open an xterm.

Comment: You don't need to do anything with xhost or X0.hosts when using X11 forwarding in ssh - it handles all the access control for you.